# Is there a way to use nexmo with a test api key?

Tags: api, api-key, vonage

I wonder how we're suppose to integrate and unittest nexmo. They don't have any test api key such as stripe, etc. They also charge you regardless of whether sms is sent or not

They don't publish numbers where you can send a messae and not get charged for. So, how do people test a nexmo integration without spending real money?

Answer (score 2):

To start using Nexmo, start off by signing up at https://dashboard.nexmo.com/sign-up

You start off with credit in your account that you can test out the apis with. As you start off with the demo, you are provided with an **api_key**, **api_secret**, and a **number** that is assigned to your account. 
You can have 10 whitelisted numbers you are allowed to use in the "to" fields (depending on which api you use).

From here, you just have to make an HTTP call to start sending your first text. You can test out the API by making the call in your application or using a site like: https://www.hurl.it/ and entering the base URL ( https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json? ) and entering the required parameters' name and value.

*Full disclosure, I work at Nexmo*

Comment: hurl.it doesn't load for me. Does it still exist?

Answer (score 1):

When you sign up for an account they give you some credit for free.  This should be enough to allow you to test, get your application working and realise if you want to use their SMS gateway in the long run.

Your best bet it to contact them.  They tend to be very quick and helpful when replying.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sandbox api that you can get a test api key.

https://labs.nexmo.com/

This is great for familiarising yourself with the api, and simulating situations that won't happen in the real world.

However it would be great to be able to use the actual api as you describe.